# React Hooks, how to share state between two functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm coming from a Vue background and I'm having a really hard time understanding how to show something conditionally when the HTML is split into multiple parts.

Suppose I got the following structure:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => setMobileNavOpen(true)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
      {mobileNavOpen && <MobileNav />}
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileNav() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => setMobileNavOpen(false)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

How would I be able to access [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] in both Home() and MobileNav(). Basically what I want to achieve is a Home Component where users can press a button upon which a MobileMenu Component opens with yet another button they can use to close the menu again.

Right now, the 2nd line from the top `const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);`
results in `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` but where would I put it?

Should this line be in the Home() Component and all child components emit an event to show or close the Menu? Or do I need a state management library for something as simple as this? What is the "React" way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setMobileNavOpen(true)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
      {mobileNavOpen && <MobileNav setMobileNavOpen={setMobileNavOpen} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileNav({setMobileNavOpen}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setMobileNavOpen(false)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

1. you have to move the useState hook to the component body
2. pass down the state setter function to your child component

Answer (score 2):

if your `Home() Component` renders `MobileNav() Component` you should put `const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false)` in `Home()` like:

```
const Home = () => {
   const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false)

   return ( 
   <>
    ...
    <MobileNav 
      handleMobileNav={mobileNavOpen}
    />
    ...
   </>)
}

const MobileNav = ({ handleMobileNav }) => {

   return <></>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to pass the state modifier down to the child component.  For this the hook needs to be moved inside the parent component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function Home() {
  const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => setMobileNavOpen(true)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
      {mobileNavOpen && <MobileNav setMobileNavOpen={setMobileNavOpen} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileNav(setMobileNavOpen) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => setMobileNavOpen(false)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Alternatively, you could abstract this a little so that your child component defines only what's required:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [mobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => setMobileNavOpen(true)}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
      {mobileNavOpen && <MobileNav onClose={() => setMobileNavOpen(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileNav(onClose) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(): void => onClose()}
        type="button"
        className="btn"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) provide some good best practices for managing shared state.

Comment: Hooks cannot be used outside if the component context. You have to move the hook into Home.

Comment: @Laszlo Cheers, I've sorted that!

Answer (score 0):

> Should this line be in the Home() Component and all child components emit an event to show or close the Menu?

Yes. 
Then pass state to the MobileNavComponent